# about 13years old Kohler Kitchen Faucet replacement

Tags: faucet, removal

I would like to take off the old kitchen faucet, but it is alot tougher than I thought! This is how it looks like, and I tried to strew the fold ring with wrench, but it does not move at all. There was 2 screws as seen as a hole in the picture, but the screws were not tightened at all. I am not sure if I am doing the right thing (try to unscrew the gold ring). Anyone has any recommendation? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Looks like that brass colored ring might be expoxied or otherwise permanently attached to the underside of the surround (is it maybe granite or something like that?). Assuming you have already undone all the hose connections below, try to turn the faucet part sticking up above the sink to unscrew it, using leather gloves or a towel to get a grip.

Comment: Have you tried angling a punch in that screw hole and tapping it with a hammer? It might start it moving.

Comment: Thanks all!!! I can finally remove the faucet. It got stucked, and took me hours to take it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there

By removing the two screws that were there to prevent the flange from turning are out.

Next use a screwdriver and unclip the metal clip on the faucet hose.

They probably used some sort of sealer between the flange and the counter board

Cut it with utility knife.

You should be ready to go (unscrew the flange)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user161288 thank me when you suceeded